# How to display SQLite database data on a fragment from a navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm struggling to show content using a navigation drawer. Basically I have a database showing five categories of noodles. each category is listed as a fragment in a navigation drawer. But I don't know how to connect an activity (for instance a list of noodles) to such a fragment. Can someone please help?
Here are my codes:

One of the five fragment classes:

```html
public class KoreanFragment extends Fragment {
        public KoreanFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_korean, container, false);

        }
    }
```

Main Activity Class displays the drawer:

```html
public class NoodleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Cursor cursor;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_noodle);
        //set up toolbar as the normal app bar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ListView noodleListPerCategory = findViewById(R.id.selected_noodleList);
        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        try {
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = database.query("NOODLE", new String[]{"_id", "NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            //create the cursor adapter to fill the list view with values from the database
            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[]{"NAME"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text2}, 0);
            noodleListPerCategory.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        //show item detail using the listener when an item is clicked
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //starts DetailActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(NoodleActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.CHOSEN_NOODLE_ITEM, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        //connects the listener to the list view
        noodleListPerCategory.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }

    /**
     *This method is called when the database and cursor need to be closed.
     * They are closed when the cursor adapter doesn't need them anymore.
     * */
    @Override
         public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
        }
    }
```

A class showing the list of noodles from a database:

```html
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //the name for the database
    private static final String DATABASENAME = "NoodleDB";
    //the initial version of the database
    private static final int DATABASEVERSION = 1;
    private Noodle noodle;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASEVERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        updateDatabase(db, 0, DATABASEVERSION);

    }

    /**
     * this method updates the database if the db helper's version number is higher than the version number on the db.
     *
     * @param db             The SQLite database
     * @param currentVersion The user's version number of the database
     * @param updatedVersion The new version of the database written in the helper's code
     */

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int currentVersion, int updatedVersion) {
        updateDatabase(db, currentVersion, updatedVersion);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when you want to set the database back to its previous version
     *
     * @param db             The SQLite database
     * @param currentVersion The user's version number of the database
     * @param updatedVersion The new version of the database written in the helper's code
     */
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int currentVersion, int updatedVersion) {

    }

    /**
     * This method is for adding new noodle dish to the database
     */
    private static void addNoodle(SQLiteDatabase database, Noodle noodle) {
        ContentValues noodleValues = new ContentValues();
        noodleValues.put("NAME", noodle.getName());
        noodleValues.put("DESCRIPTION", noodle.getDescription());
        noodleValues.put("IMAGEID", noodle.getPhotoID());
        noodleValues.put("RESTAURANT", noodle.getSuggestedRestaurant());
        database.insert("NOODLE", null, noodleValues);
        database.close();

    }

    private void updateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int currentVersion, int updatedVersion) {
        if(currentVersion >= 1 || currentVersion < 1 ) {
            //execute SQL on the db and create a new NOODLE table
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE NOODLE ("
                    + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "NAME TEXT, "
                    + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, "
                    + "IMAGEID INTEGER, "
                    + "RESTAURANT TEXT, "
                    + "FAVORITE NUMERIC, "
                    + "CATEGORY TEXT);");
            addNoodle(db, new Noodle("Spicy Ramen", "Chicken broth, marinated pork, chilli and bean sprouts", R.drawable.spicyramen, "Totemo", "japanese"));
            addNoodle(db, new Noodle("Tokyo Ramen", "Dashi-based broth, marinated pork and fermented bamboo shoots", R.drawable.tokyo, "Totemo", "japanese"));
            addNoodle(db, new Noodle("Vegetarian Ramen", "Mushroom dashi-based broth, tofu, pak choi, miso and corn", R.drawable.vegetarianramen, "Ramen Manga", "japanese"));
            addNoodle(db, new Noodle("Miso Ramen", "Miso broth, marinated pork, egg, spring onion and bean sprouts", R.drawable.miso, "Cafe Steigman", "japanese"));
            addNoodle(db, new Noodle("Tonkatsu Ramen", "Pork bone based broth, grilled pork, spicy garlic with miso", R.drawable.tonkatsu, "Blue Light Yokohama", "japanese"));
            addNoodle(db, new Noodle("Shio Ramen", "Seasalt broth, pork, egg, quail and vegetable", R.drawable.shio, "Ai Ramen", "japanese"));
            addNoodle(db, new Noodle("Nabeyaki Udon", "Udon noodles in fish broth with chicken, shrimp, egg and leek", R.drawable.udon, "Ki-mama Ramen", "japanese"));
        }
        if(currentVersion <=2) {

        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper class

```html
public class NoodleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Cursor cursor;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_noodle);
        //set up toolbar as the normal app bar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ListView noodleListPerCategory = findViewById(R.id.selected_noodleList);
        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        try {
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = database.query("NOODLE", new String[]{"_id", "NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            //create the cursor adapter to fill the list view with values from the database
            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[]{"NAME"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text2}, 0);
            noodleListPerCategory.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        //show item detail using the listener when an item is clicked
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //starts DetailActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(NoodleActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.CHOSEN_NOODLE_ITEM, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        //connects the listener to the list view
        noodleListPerCategory.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }

    /**
     *This method is called when the database and cursor need to be closed.
     * They are closed when the cursor adapter doesn't need them anymore.
     * */
    @Override
         public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
        }
 }
```

Right now....the database is not created and I don't know how to display data on the fragments, let alone filtered by category. :(

Comment: That is a lot of code to take in. If you narrowed down the source code to the essential, you would have a much better change of getting an answer.

Comment: Sorry, but you dumping like 200 lines of code on us?! Please read about creating a minimal viable complete example(stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you have to do is create an instance of you DatabaseHelper and then access the database from that either via an SQLiteDatabase instance or via methods within or via the DatabaseHelper as you would from an activity. You do need a Context, which can be obtained via the `getActivity` method or the `getContext` method.

e.g. (assuming you your `KoreanFragment` is where you wish to access the database and display the data; and that the data is to be displayed via a ListView ) :-

```
    public class KoreanFragment extends Fragment {

        Databasehelper mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(getContext()); //<<<<<<<<
        SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = mDBHlpr.getWriteableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<
        ListView mMyListView; //<<<<<<<< 
        SimpleCursorAdpater mSCA; //<<<<<<<<
        Cursor mCsr; //<<<<<<<<

        //????????Alternative SQLiteDatabase = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getWriteableDatabase();

        public KoreanFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_korean, container, false); //<<<<<<<< don't return as yet
            mMyListView = view.findViewByid(R.id.mylistview); //<<<<<<<< get the Listview to be populated

            mCsr = getAllRows(); //<<<<<<<< get data as cursor
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mCsr,new String[]{"NAME"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0); //<<<<<<<< prepare adapater for ListView
            mMyListView.setAdapter(mSCA); //<<<<<<<< attach the adapter to the ListView
            return view; //<<<<<<<<

        }

        //<<<<<<<< new method to query the database an extract all rows from the NOODLE table
        private Cursor getAllRows() {
             return mDatabase.query("NOODLE",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        }
    }
```

You should really close the Cursor when done with it so you might add the following to overide the onDetach method:-

```
        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mCsr.close();
        }
```

You may wish to make use of the List e.g. to delete a row if it is longClicked.

This could be done by **1)** adding the following method :-

```
        private void setItemLongClickListener() {
            mMyListview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mDatabase.delete("NOODLE","_id=?",new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
                mCsr = getAllRows();
                mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

and **2)** adding the following line immediately after the line `mMyListView.setAdapter(mSCA);` :-

```
        setItemLongClickListener();
```

Notes

- I've indicated the new/changed code using **`//<<<<<<<<`**
- The above is in-principle/theory code as opposed to tested code so there may be typos or errors.
- **`mylistview`** as in `mMyListView = view.findViewByid(R.id.`**`mylistview`**`);` would very likely have to be added to the layout, likely with a name to suit your naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks! But I tried to implement your code in the fragment but now the app doesn't even start anymore :')